# AnyChart within reusable component not appearing in correct DOM position (Angular 9.1.3, Bootstrap 4.4.1, Anychart 8.7.1)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, anychart

I am doing a simple test dashboard with two Bootstrap cards, each containing an Anychart column chart. The goal is to play with reusable components.

Here is a link to the code on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anychart-containter-test)

When I run the code, I expect to see the second chart within the body of second card. However when I check the DOM via Dev Tools in the browser (Chrome), I see that the second chart appears to be drawn right under the first chart within the first card's `<app-bar-chart>` tag. And neither chart appears within the `<app-bar-chart>` tag of the second card. You can see the second chart filling the space behind the two cards.

I tried using Bootstrap `"container"` as well as `"row/col-12"` class tags at a few levels, but no luck.

The overall outline of the components are as follows:

```
  app.component               (dashboard)
  |--card.component           (reusable card, data 1)
     |--bar-chart.component   (reusable chart)
  |--card.component           (reusable card, data 2)
     |--bar-chart.component   (reusable chart)
```

Thank you for any thoughts, pointers, and suggestions in advance!

Comment: this problem does not come from CSS or bootstrap, it comes from TS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about TS but yes, I know how JS works so from JS perspective I gave you an answer.

This problem comes from TS, when you call

> `<app-card-component [dataSet]="dataSet1" [title]="'Data Set 1'"></app-card-component>`

above code, it renders card component and goes for `bar-chart` component and it will find 
`this.chart.container("chartContainer");` that code when you want to draw your `anychart` so, it will find in DOM and assign that chart in `chartContainer` and after that, you call

> `<app-card-component [dataSet]="dataSet2" [title]="'Data Set 2'"></app-card-component>`

and the same process will happen that I described above.

so every time, you call that `app-card-component` it will assign your chart below your previous chart, so

The solution is to give an index to the every id and make dynamic `chartContainer`. like `chartContainer1`, `chartContainer2` and so on..